# Вопрос по поводу адресации

Tags: ассемблер

Здравствуйте.

Возник вопрос, почему именно так работает, а не по-другому.

Пример:

```
.MODEL tiny   
.DATA
   x DW 3
.CODE
   mov Ax,Cs:x        ; в регистр Ax будет передано значение x, хотя x не находится
                      ; в сегменте кода (Cs), а располагается в сегменте данных (Ds).
                      ; Кстати, если использовать Ds, то ЗНАЧЕНИЕ не будет получено.
   mov Ax,4C00h
   int 21h
END
```

Comment: Я уже про модели плохо помню, но предположу, что model tiny предполагает несегментированный блок памяти, а также предполагает `ASSUME CS:CODE` (`DS:CODE` - неверно)

Comment: да, почитал про это. так и есть.
спасибо.

Comment: @Angry Bird, @ХэшКод, по-моему, эти три метки можно смело объединить в одну.

Comment: Ещё один вопрос для общества археологов. Ассемблер ископаемого микропроцессора под управлением давно умершей операционки.

Comment: @alexlz, везде во всех ВУЗах России учат ассемблер для реального режима. Не пойму, зачем. Какая в этом польза? Мозги студентам прочистить?

Comment: @mikillskegg Наличие литературы, методических пособий, отработанные программы. Плюс у студентов повышает ощущение собственной крутости. Ну архитектура всё же похожа на современные x86. А вообще -- так сложилось. Традиция, блин.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Tiny*-model programs run only under
> MS-DOS. *Tiny* model places all data and
> code in a **single** segment. Therefore,
> the total program file size can occupy
> no more than 64K.

Паста из [лекций по MASM](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Directives/lecture.html#D77_0030_models).

Comment: Дополню, при модели памяти Tiny регистры CS, DS, SS равны между собой.